# How to test an expected 404 response with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to create a JMeter test that will request a page that I expect to return a 404 and assert that that is in fact what is returned.
Typically, JMeter will treat a 404 response as a failure for an assertion.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Create a new Response Assertion under the test.
In the "Response Field to Test" section of the assertion, make sure to check the box for "Ignore Status".

You can then add other assertions as you'd like, such as setting the radio in "Response Field to Test" to "Response Code" and setting the "Patterns to Test" to 404.

(h/t http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Making-HTTP-404-a-test-success-tp5713923p5713941.html)

Answer (score 16):

Use a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) that you add as child of HTTP Request:

Check:

- Ignore status so that 404 is not considered an error
- Fields to test : Response code
- Pattern matching Rules : Equals
- Patterns to test : 404

[image: Configuration of Response Assertion]